# How can I implement a theme with multiple html pages and multiple js/css files in an ASP.NET MVC 5 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates

I would like to use a theme with multiple html pages and multiple css/js files but cannot find a set of instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootswatch, https://bootswatch.com/, which contains themes for Bootstrap. Download the css of the theme you'd like to apply. For example put the flatly.bootstrap.css and flatly.bootstrap.min.css files in the Content folder (be sure to Include in Project as well).

This is assuming you're using the default _Layout.cshtml.

BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
"~/Content/bootstrap.css",
"~/Content/site.css"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
"~/Content/flatly.bootstrap.css",
"~/Content/site.css"));
```